# Changing the font color of a accompanying text item in a CheckListCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython

How do I change the font color of a selected  item in a CheckListCtrl ?  For a selected item I would like the change the color of text in the accompanying text of the selected item ?

```
class CheckListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin): 
    def __init__(self, parent):     
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, -1,style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)          
        CheckListCtrlMixin.__init__(self)             
        ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)
```

Comment: Use the edition icon ({}) to format your code as I did, no tags. In this way your code will be perfectly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need [this](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html):

```
self.list.SetItemTextColour(index, colour)
```